# Editing an approved opportunity to trigger re-approval

Tags: trigger, process-builder, after-trigger, approval-process

When an opportunity is submitted for approval, the opportunity owner can edit the opportunity and add values/ changes that are not approved, I don't want to lock the opportunity as that would create a bottleneck. I want to make it so when a change happens after the opportunity is submitted for approval a trigger will send the opportunity for re-approval.

Is it possible to make the trigger through process builder? I want to avoid apex and flow if possible as I'm a beginner in them.

currently, I tried to make the trigger look at the last modified by field if the time value is greater than than the Date field in the approval history object then it will trigger for re-approval.

There are 2 main issues with that.

1. the last modified by field looks like a time field but it's not ( its an ID)
2. I don't want the trigger to fire when the opportunity is moved to contracted.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). By asking "How...", are you asking for overall design & implementation options - like Flow vs. Process Builder vs. Apex?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Moonpie thank you for the feedback, does the question make more sense now?

Comment: Hamza, it helps some. So you are attempting to write an Apex trigger?

Comment: I want to avoid apex and flow if possible as I'm a beginner in them.

Comment: Thank you for that important information. When you say "approved" Opportunity, are you using an actual Salesforce [Approval Process](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.what_are_approvals.htm&type=5), or is this your own internal business version of an approval?

Comment: It's the salesforce approval process ( the user can submit the opportunity for approval and the manager can approve it.) when submitted and when approved it will show up under the approval history object ( this object is not accessible in the object manager in setup.)